# Problema al buscar un dato en un array de estructuras

Tags: array, c

El problema que tengo es que tengo este codigo, al ejecutarlo y llamar a la funcion buscar con la opcion del menu 2 e introducir el nif del cliente me sale como que no ha encontrado al cliente aunque lo haya introducido antes, he implementado la funcion para limpiar el buffer de entrada para asegurarme de que no es ese el problema y ya me estoy volviendo loco.

Dejo por aquí el codigo de la funcion buscar que creo que es la que da problemas:

```
void buscar(struct Cliente registros[], int numRegistros, const char *nif) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numRegistros; i++) {
        if (strcmp(registros[i].NIF, nif) == 0) {
            printf("\nCliente encontrado:");
            printf("\nNIF: %s", registros[i].NIF);
            printf("\nNombre: %s", registros[i].Nombre);
            printf("\nDireccion: %s", registros[i].Direccion);
            printf("\nTelefono: %s", registros[i].Telefono);
            printf("\nUltima visita: %d/%d/%d", registros[i].ultimaVisita.dia, registros[i].ultimaVisita.mes, registros[i].ultimaVisita.anio);
            printf("\nObservaciones: %s", registros[i].observaciones);
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("\nCliente no encontrado.");
}
```

Como no estoy seguro dejo el código completo del programa por aquí:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_NIF 9
#define MAX_REGISTROS 50
#define MAX_NOMBRE 40
#define MAX_OBSERVACIONES 100
#define MAX_DIRECCION 100
#define MAX_TLF 9

struct fecha {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anio;
};

struct Cliente {
    char NIF[MAX_NIF];
    char Nombre[MAX_NOMBRE];
    char Direccion[MAX_DIRECCION];
    char Telefono[MAX_TLF];
    struct fecha ultimaVisita;
    char observaciones[MAX_OBSERVACIONES];
};

void introducirDatos(struct Cliente registros[], int maxRegistros, int *numRegistros);
void buscar(struct Cliente registros[], int numRegistros, const char *nif);
void menuPrincipal(struct Cliente registros[], int numRegistros);
void limpiarBuffer();

int main() {
    struct Cliente registros[MAX_REGISTROS];
    int numRegistros = 0;

    menuPrincipal(registros, numRegistros);

    return 0;
}

void introducirDatos(struct Cliente registros[], int maxRegistros, int *numRegistros) {
    int i;
    char opcion;

    for (i = *numRegistros; i < maxRegistros; i++) {
        do {
            printf("\nNIF: ");
            scanf("%9s", registros[i].NIF);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (strlen(registros[i].NIF) != MAX_NIF);

        do {
            printf("\nNombre: ");
            scanf("%39[^\n]", registros[i].Nombre);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (strlen(registros[i].Nombre) >= MAX_NOMBRE);

        do {
            printf("\nDireccion: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]", registros[i].Direccion);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (strlen(registros[i].Direccion) >= MAX_DIRECCION);

        do {
            printf("\nTelefono: ");
            scanf("%8s", registros[i].Telefono);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (strlen(registros[i].Telefono) >= MAX_TLF);

        do {
            printf("\nDia ultima visita: ");
            scanf("%d", &registros[i].ultimaVisita.dia);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (registros[i].ultimaVisita.dia > 31 || registros[i].ultimaVisita.dia < 1);

        do {
            printf("\nMes ultima visita: ");
            scanf("%d", &registros[i].ultimaVisita.mes);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (registros[i].ultimaVisita.mes > 12 || registros[i].ultimaVisita.mes < 1);

        do {
            printf("\nAnio ultima visita: ");
            scanf("%d", &registros[i].ultimaVisita.anio);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (registros[i].ultimaVisita.anio < 1);

        do {
            printf("\nObservaciones: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]", registros[i].observaciones);
            limpiarBuffer();
        } while (strlen(registros[i].observaciones) >= MAX_OBSERVACIONES);

        (*numRegistros)++;

        printf("\nCliente agregado correctamente.");
        printf("\nNumero de pacientes en la lista: %d", *numRegistros);
        printf("\n¿Deseas introducir otro paciente? (S/N): ");
        scanf(" %c", &opcion);
        limpiarBuffer();

        if (opcion == 'N' || opcion == 'n') {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void buscar(struct Cliente registros[], int numRegistros, const char *nif) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numRegistros; i++) {
        if (strcmp(registros[i].NIF, nif) == 0) {
            printf("\nCliente encontrado:");
            printf("\nNIF: %s", registros[i].NIF);
            printf("\nNombre: %s", registros[i].Nombre);
            printf("\nDireccion: %s", registros[i].Direccion);
            printf("\nTelefono: %s", registros[i].Telefono);
            printf("\nUltima visita: %d/%d/%d", registros[i].ultimaVisita.dia, registros[i].ultimaVisita.mes, registros[i].ultimaVisita.anio);
            printf("\nObservaciones: %s", registros[i].observaciones);
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("\nCliente no encontrado.");
}

void menuPrincipal(struct Cliente registros[], int numRegistros) {
    int opcion;
    char nif[MAX_NIF];

    do {
        printf("\n--- MENU PRINCIPAL ---");
        printf("\n1 - Introducir datos");
        printf("\n2 - Buscar cliente por NIF");
        printf("\n3 - Salir");
        printf("\nSelecciona una opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);
        limpiarBuffer();

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                introducirDatos(registros, MAX_REGISTROS, &numRegistros);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nIntroduce el NIF del cliente: ");
                scanf("%9s", nif);
                limpiarBuffer();
                buscar(registros, numRegistros, nif);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nSaliendo del programa...");
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nOpcion invalida. Intentalo nuevamente.");
                break;
        }
    } while (opcion != 3);
}

void limpiarBuffer() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene del tamaño del campo NIF de la struct Cliente. En la función `introducirDatos` introduces 9 bytes en un array de 9 bytes.
En la función buscar, en `strcmp(registros[i].NIF, nif) == 0`  el primer parámetro no incluye el `/0` final del string por lo que se concatena con el siguiente campo (Nombre). Compararás, por ejemplo, algo así como 123456789Ana y 123456789.

Tal y como tienes el código, para solucionar el problema puedes incrementar el tamaño del campo NIF
`char NIF[MAX_NIF+1];`

Comment: Hmm, no veo donde crea una copia local de la estructura

Comment: No se crea una copia local, quizá me he expresado mal. Pero se pasa los valores de una struct a la función de manera que a la salida de la función la struct original no ha cambiado. En mi solución se pasa la struct como referencia, así que tras la salida de la función los cambios realizados en la misma permanecen

Comment: Con los parámetros a funciones pasa algo interesante: los que se definan como array el compilador intentara averiguar el tamaño del array que se ingreso, sino lo sabe lo pasa igual. Pero realmente el compilador convierte de struct Cliente *registros[] a struct Cliente **registros, Solo que el compilador intenta verificar si el array pasado no supera el tamaño de lo que quiere pasar. Te sugiero leer: [Passing an array as an argument to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Nunca te irás a dormir sin aprender algo nuevo. Muchas gracias por el apunte @DanielBriceño. Edito la respuesta en consecuencia

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque `scanf` no está considerando el último carácter al final de la cadena.

Usaría [*fgets*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fgets.html), tiene sus ventajas, como leer espacios en blanco y manejar mejor los buffers, a diferencia de scanf, que no incluye la lectura de string  pero incluso fgets leerá el carácter `'\n'`

```
fgets(registros[i].NIF, sizeof(registros[i].NIF), stdin);
registros[i].NIF[strlen(registros[i].NIF) - 1] = '\0';
```

Para que o `scanf` considere o caractere nulo de terminação `'\0'` no final da `string`, a correção será:

```
registros[i].NIF[MAX_NIF - 1] = '\0';
```

las dos alternativas:

**fgets**

```
do {
    printf("\nNIF: ");
    fgets(registros[i].NIF, sizeof(registros[i].NIF), stdin);
    limpiarBuffer();
} while (strlen(registros[i].NIF) != MAX_NIF);

registros[i].NIF[strlen(registros[i].NIF) - 1] = '\0';
```

**scanf**

```
do {
    printf("\nNIF: ");
    scanf("%9s", registros[i].NIF);
    limpiarBuffer();
} while (strlen(registros[i].NIF) != MAX_NIF);

registros[i].NIF[MAX_NIF - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Como ya respondí, conozco los términos de la comunidad y no usaría inteligencia artificial para generar respuestas, respeto mucho a los usuarios y entiendo que necesitan ayuda de un ser humano con experiencia en la vida en el área tecnológica.